# React Leaflet update position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, leaflet, react-leaflet

I've got a question about React Leaflet. I am now trying to build a PWA with the react framework and I need to use a map, hence React Leaflet.

So here's the situation :

I need to load the Map when I go on the map page and it must be at the current location I am in. I made a Map component that is on the App.js file :

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Map />
  );
}
export default App;
```

In my Map component, I currently don't have much because I changed lots of things that didn't work.

```
function Map() {
  
    return (
      <>
        <MapContainer center={[46.8182, 8.2275]} zoom={12} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          <ResetView />
        </MapContainer>
      </>
    )
  }

export default Map;
```

I looked at all those websites and tried understanding how to do it but never really got anything right :

https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-animated-panning/

https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-external-state/

https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/qol90a/set_position_of_the_react_leaflet_map/

So what I would like to do is to get the current location with this :

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();`

And when the current location returns the longitude and latitude, to pan the map to where those coordinates are.

I hope I was clear enough and thank everyone for any kind of help !

I tried to send the location through props. I tried to get the location and load the Map component through React hooks but nothing seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to do it correctly it's alright.

```
function ChangeLocation(location) {
  const map = useMap();
  map.panTo([location.location.lat, location.location.lng]);
}

function Map() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState();

  const getLocation = () => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((data) => {
        setLocation({ lng: data.coords.longitude, lat: data.coords.latitude });
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Géolocalisation pas supportée");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getLocation();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          navigator.geolocation
            ? getLocation()
            : console.log("Géolocalisation pas supportée");
        }}
      >
        Center
      </button>
      <MapContainer center={[46.8182, 8.2275]} zoom={12} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        {location ? <ChangeLocation location={location} /> : ""}
      </MapContainer>
    </>
  );
}
export default Map;
```

If there is a better way or that that code isn't right, please let me know !